# Why might this disable other functionality?

Tags: wp-admin

I've noticed that with my custom post types, removing support for 'excerpt' disables the 'screen options' and 'add new category' functionality... the button and link are present, but do nothing.

I use excerpts, so aren't about to have a problem - but I'm wondering whether this is usual or if I'll have to root-through my functions.php in search of a possible cause?

NEXT-DAY UPDATE.

With a clear head... of course this isn't usual (duh!), and I forgot to mention the console shows an error - included below, though I'm not smart enough to understand.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (post.php?post=10518&action=edit:119)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

The cause of the problem seems to be a function (containing jQuery) which adds a character count to the excerpt field...

```
function excerpt_count_js() {

if ( 'page' != get_post_type() ) {

echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:12px;right:34px;color:#666;\"><small>Excerpt length: </small><span id=\"excerpt_counter\"></span><span style=\"font-weight:bold; padding-left:7px;\">/ 150</span><small><span style=\"font-weight:bold; padding-left:7px;\">character(s).</span></small></div>" );
jQuery("span#excerpt_counter").text(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length );
jQuery("#excerpt").keyup(function() {
if(jQuery(this).val().length > 500) {
jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().substr(0, 500) );
}
jQuery("span#excerpt_counter").text(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length );
} );
} );</script>';
} }
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'excerpt_count_js' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'excerpt_count_js' );
```

Commenting-out:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'excerpt_count_js' );
```

restores correct function of 'screen options' and 'add category', but of course removes the character count

Comment: Do they totally disable the button? That seems like a JavaScript problem to me, since screen option does a dozen of more tasks other than toggling excerpt.

Comment: + 1 to Jack Johansson. Check browser js console for errors.

Comment: @Jack Johansson ...thanks. Yes, totally disables it - clicking does nothing other than show the link outline. I've updated my original post - it's now hopefully less stupid.

Comment: @Anton Lukin ... thanks. Good point. I've update my original post - I forgot to mention I'd seen the console error before posting, but don't know enough to understand.